# Multiprocessing CPU utilization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am using the Pool function to run a group of command line executable (~200) with a python script. I import the command line executable from a .csv file. I am running on AWS instance with a machine that has 96 cores. However I am noticing that my cpu utilization is 100%. Do I need to close a Pool instance after it has been executed?

```
import csv
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

def import_executables(file):
    f = open(file)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

    executables = []

    for row in csv_f:
        executables.append(row[0])

    executables_tuple = tuple([name] for name in executables)

    return executables_tuple

work = import_executables('output.csv')

def work_log(work_data):
    print("Process %s executing" % (work_data))
    subprocess.call(work_data, shell=True)

def pool_handler():
    p = Pool(10)
    p.map(work_log, work)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool_handler()
```

Comment: What sort of commands do you with `subprocess.call`? As far as I can see multiprocessing will run only 10 additional processes and thus should use at most 1 + 10 cores.

Comment: The command is executing a matlab binary. So I figure at most each pool would use a single core, one for the pool and one for the matlab binary executable.

Comment: Does the matlab binary run multi-threaded computations? Try running something like the `grep` command instead of matlab and see if you get the expected behavior.